# What is the meaning of "Theoretical possibility"

Tags: meaning, modal-verbs

I don't know the meaning of "Theoretical possibility" . I am learning modal verb "can" which is used to refer "Theoretical possibilty".I don't know if something is a theoretical possibility what does it mean. I have been searching its meaning on Internet but didn't find any explaination. I wish someone here could explain me the meaning of it with context.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: What does "theoretical" mean?  What does "possibility" mean?  Your question should include this information, to prove you did your research.  And you should also include the full context of using "can" with "theoretical possibility".

Answer (score 5):

Something is said to be theoretically possible if there is no reason why it could never happen.  Actually though, we are practically certain it never will.

How many tables does a restaurant in a large hotel need for breakfast? It is theoretically possible that all the guests will come at the same time so, in theory, we need enough tables so that all the guests can have breakfast at the same time. In practice, as opposed to theory, we know that they will not all come at the same time, so how many do we really think is the most that will turn up at once? The practical assumed limit will be much lower than the theoretical limit.

A life insurance company knows that it is theoretically possible that all its policyholders will die tomorrow, and all its pensioners will live to be a hundred and ten. In practice we know, or almost know, that will not happen.

So saying that something is theoretically possible means that it could happen, but is so absurdly unlikely we can ignore it in real life.

It is theoretically possible I will win the lottery jackpot every week for the next year, but I am planning on the assumption I might not. Actually though I do not enter the lottery so it is not even theoretically possible I could win it - it is absolutely and completely impossible.

Comment: Your explaination means, in short, that if something is a theoretical possibility there is no reason that it won't happen in the future or be (or not) the case in the present. Am I correct?

Comment: Yes Sanjay, partly. When we say something is a possibility we mean it can happen. When we say something is a theoretical possibility we also mean it can happen, but as well as that we mean it is so unlikely that we can, for practical purposes, treat it as something that won't ever happen. It is a theoretical possibility because it can happen, but it is regarded as a practical impossibility because it is so extremely unlikely.  We do not need to plan for it.    Theoretically it can happen. For practical purposes we assume it is so unlikely we treat it as if   it was impossible.

Comment: "Glass can be blown"- it is a theoretical possibility ( as mentioned on some website).Could you explain why it is so? It would help me understand it quite clearly.

Comment: @Sanjay In this case, I think "can" combines possibility and ability. "Glass can be blown" means that it is POSSIBLE to manufacture glass by blowing, or that glass manufacturers are ABLE to manufacture glass by blowing into it. Don't worry too much about "theoretical" in that case. See how MAY can be used to express PROBABILITY: "The wind is blowing the curtains. The glass miniatures on the table MAY break. Close the window right now."

Comment: Theoretically speaking, "theoretically" might not imply "unlikely". It doesn't dramatically change the meaning to remove the "theoretical" in "theoretical possibility". I don't think you can have a possibility that's not theoretical in some sense, given that theory underpins our understanding of reality.

Answer (score 3):

Books on modals usually reserve the term "theoretical possibility" for "can", as opposed to "actual possibility" or "probability", which would be the case of "may".

The difference they want to make is that "can" does not mean that something is likely to happen, but merely that the event or action in question is not impossible.

Compare:

- It's sunny, but in this tropical weather, it **can** rain anytime. (This does not mean that there is any probability of raining, but that the possibility of rain always exists).
- It's cloudy. I think it **may** rain in the afternoon. (The chances that it will rain are high because it is cloudy.)

The difference between possibility and probability is even philosophical, and is thus reflected by grammar.

Comment: Another way of expressing the idea in your second sentence: if 'A' is theoretically possible then the strongest statement you can make about its likelihood is that it's not impossible for 'A' to happen. I'm not quite comfortable with the sentiment, "nothing is impossible."

Comment: @user888379 It's true that "nothing is impossible" sounds like a bit too much, and will edit my answer accordingly. When I wrote it, I was thinking of the sentence "Anything CAN happen" as opposed to the incorrect "Anything MAY happen".

Answer (score 0):

This answer is intended more to provide context and understanding of what underlies your question than to get into the the definition of "theoretical possibility".  Your confusion is understandable (and I'll suggest would have been avoidable if not for your choice of reference; the problem lies with a poor source rather than with you).  You found a definition of "can" that used the description "theoretical possibility", and now you're trying to understand that phrase.

davidlol's answer does a good job of describing what "theoretical possibility" means in the abstract sense.  In typical usage, it distinguishes between expected probability and the extreme limit of possibility.  That's a direct answer to what is asked in the question, and perhaps illustrates why the term would be confusing when used to define the word "can".

Gustavson's answer describes its usage in defining the word "can".  There, "theoretical" isn't intended in the more literal sense of davidlol's answer.  It's usage in defining "can" is more figurative, in this case almost redundant with "possibility".

There actually is one usage of "can" that only works in spoken language unless you use some form of highlighting in printed text to make the usage clear.  It stresses the word "can" in the sentence to imply unlikelihood, often in a sarcastic sense.  "Do you think I can win the lottery?"  "Sure, you **can** win."  Perhaps it's use in the definition was meant to reflect that usage.  In that case, "theoretical possibility" is an accurate description.

As far as general usage, though, the definition of "can" is more accurate leaving out the word "theoretical" because it is really too strong a word, as indicated by the confusion it caused due to it's typical meaning.  Except for that one usage, "can" refers to something that is a possibility rather than a certainty, not something that is only a remote possibility.  So using a descriptor that is typically used to mean that can be somewhat misleading or confusing.  In fact, I spot-checked definitions in various online dictionaries and all the ones I checked do not include the word "theoretical", they use just "possibility" for this associated meaning.

Comment: "theoretical possibility" may sound redundant, but as a teacher of English I can assure you that saying that something is possible "in theory" is quite effective, particularly when the students are not familiar with the "philosophical" difference between "possibility" and "probability" (they sometimes use "possible/y" and "probable/y" indistinctly, either in English or in their native language. I find davidlol's comment above especially enlightening (and gave him an upvote for that reason) when he makes a difference between something being possible "in theory" though not "in practice".

Comment: @Gustavson, I agree (and BTW, I thought both of your answers were good and upvoted both).  By "redundant", I was referring only to the usage in a definition of "can".

Comment: Thank you. I admit that it is a vice inherent to the definition of "can" mainly by some ESL books. My native language is Spanish, and we use the same verb "poder" to mean both "can" and "may". As you will imagine, speaking about "theoretical" and "practical" possibility is essential for some students to decide when to use which.

Answer (score -1):

Low probability events have been stated in other answers .This is correct.Also there are things that can be done but are not practical .Here are some examples from an engineering context.It would have been possible to have cellphones in WW2 but such a phone would need a small truck to fit it in and the power needed would slow the truck down and make it use more fuel.It is possible to make a steam powered car today that would run on kerosine but the fuel economy would be terrible by modern standards . It is possible to have a car battery that would outlive the car but it would be about three times as heavy ,cost more and be more prone to run flat when the car is not in use.It is possible to have a filament lightbulb last many times longer than existing ones do ,but it would cost more , use more power and produce a dim yellow light.The list could go on forever.Many things while possible in theory are just not on when it comes to practice.